# When to use android search dialogue

Tags: android, search

I was looking for `Search Display Controller` equivalent for android and found http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

It seems to try to offer a lot of functionality for search and I'm not sure I need it.

On initial loading, 
I want to show a list of items.
When a user enters query and hit search, I'll show new list of results returned from server.
When a user cancels search, he will see the initial list of items again.

iOS's search display controller helps to implement scenario. Is there similar class for android?